# Search a attribute in a xml document with java and XPath

Tags: java, xml

i have the following method in java:

```
private static String getAttributValue(String attribute, String xmlResponseBody) {

    String searchAttributeValue = "";
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlResponseBody)));
        XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
        try {
            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("@" + attribute);
            Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) result;
            Node node = nodeList.item(0);  // something wrong??
            searchAttributeValue = node.getTextContent();

        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException sae) {
        sae.printStackTrace();
    }
    return searchAttributeValue;
}
```

I search an attribute (parameter "attribute") in a xml document (parameter "xmlResponseBody"). I would like to use XPath to solve this task. At the code, which i have comment with "// something wrong", the variable node is null. What should i do? What is the mistake in my code?

Thanks !
Marwief

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to answer this without seeing the sample xml(or part of it), but you can search for an attribute using

```
xpath.compile("//@" + attribute)
```

It means search for attribute named *attribute* inside context node and its descendants. You can get more information [here](http://www.vipan.com/htdocs/xmlHelp.html).